# Training with spacy on full dataset

Tags: spacy

When I train my spacy model as follows

```
spacy train config.cfg --paths.train ./train.spacy --paths.dev ./dev.spacy
```

the model gets trained on `train.spacy` data file, and scored on `dev.spacy`. Then `output_updated/model-best` is the model with the highest score.

Is this best model finally trained on a combination of both train and dev data? I understand, it makes sense to split those datasets to avoid overfitting, but given little training data, I would like the final model to be trained on all data I have at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, spaCy does not automatically merge your datasets before training `model-best`. If you want to do that you would need to manually create a new training data set.

If you have so little data that seems like a good idea, you should probably prioritize getting more data.